# How to add right click menu in eclipse plugin programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin with a View part. In this View part I have a table and I want to add a submenu when a user right clicks on a row in that table. How can I do this programatically?

I have defined the command and menuContribution in my plugin.xml:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
        allPopups="true"
        class="com.sintec.eclipseplugins.clippy.menu.DeleteMenuContribution"
        locationURI="menu:delete?after=additions">
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

I have also created the contribution class extending ExtensionContributionFactory:

```
public class DeleteMenuContribution extends ExtensionContributionFactory {

@Override
public void createContributionItems(IServiceLocator serviceLocator, IContributionRoot additions) {
    // build a couple of command-based contribution parameters
    CommandContributionItemParameter pAA = new CommandContributionItemParameter(
        serviceLocator,
        "DeleteCommand",
        "com.sintec.eclipseplugins.clippy.delete",
        SWT.PUSH);
    pAA.label = "Delete Command";

    // create actual contribution items and add them to the given additions reference
    CommandContributionItem itemAA = new CommandContributionItem(pAA);
    itemAA.setVisible(true);
    additions.addContributionItem(itemAA, null);

}

}
```

Aaaand last but not least I have this code my ViewPart where I want to add the menu to the table:

```
IMenuManager mgr = new MenuManager().findMenuUsingPath("menu:delete?after=additions");
MenuManager mgr2 = new MenuManager();
mgr2.add(mgr);
tableViewer.getTable().setMenu(mgr2.createContextMenu(tableViewer.getTable()));
```

The problem is that the menu can not be found. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something ... Is the menu URI correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kind of taking a stab at this ... but why don't you assign the menu an id and use the [find(id)](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/ContributionManager.html#find%28java.lang.String%29) method in the MenuManager?

Comment: Because I was using a tutorial that suggested the findMenuUsingPath() method. ;D I'm new to the RCP framework and still trying to figure out how things work. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it as soon as my computer is up and running again. :)